# Ignore "Do you wish to save" box on exit of excel

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have a script that opens an excel file and runs a macro, then quits the file. Since the file is in read only mode, and the script makes temporary changes to the file, when the script calls `myExcelWorker.Quit()` excel asks if I want to save my changes and I must click 'no'. Is there any way to exit the program and skip this box?

```
' Create a WshShell to get the current directory
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Create an Excel instance
Dim myExcelWorker
Set myExcelWorker = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 

myExcelWorker.Visible = True

' Tell Excel what the current working directory is 
' (otherwise it can't find the files)
Dim strSaveDefaultPath
Dim strPath
strSaveDefaultPath = myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath
strPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strPath

' Open the Workbook specified on the command-line 
Dim oWorkBook
Dim strWorkerWB
strWorkerWB = strPath & "\BugHistogram_v2.xlsm"

Set oWorkBook = myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Open(strWorkerWB)

' Build the macro name with the full path to the workbook
Dim strMacroName
strMacroName = "CreateImagesButton_Click"
on error resume next 
   ' Run the calculation macro
   myExcelWorker.Run strMacroName
   if err.number <> 0 Then
      ' Error occurred - just close it down.
   End If
   err.clear
on error goto 0 

' oWorkBook.Save ' this is ignored because it's read only 

myExcelWorker.DefaultFilePath = strSaveDefaultPath

' Clean up and shut down
Set oWorkBook = Nothing

' Don’t Quit() Excel if there are other Excel instances 
' running, Quit() will 
' shut those down also
if myExcelWorker.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
   myExcelWorker.Quit
End If

myExcelWorker.Quit()

Set myExcelWorker = Nothing
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ActiveWorkbook.Close False` (to close the workbook)

`Application.Quit` (to quit Excel - doesn't prompt to save changes)

From Microsoft Support's [How to suppress "Save Changes" prompt when you close a workbook in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213428):

> To force a workbook to close without saving any changes, type the
>   following code in a Visual Basic module of that workbook:
>
> ```vb
> Sub Auto_Close()
>     ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
> End Sub
> ```
>
> Because the Saved property is set to True, Excel responds as though the workbook has already been saved and no changes have
>   occurred since that last save.
>
> The **DisplayAlerts** property of the program can be used for the same
>   purpose. For example, the following macro turns **DisplayAlerts** off,
>   closes the active workbook without saving changes, and then turns
>   **DisplayAlerts** on again.
>
> ```vb
> Sub CloseBook()
>     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
>     ActiveWorkbook.Close
>     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
> End Sub
> ```
>
> You can also use the **SaveChanges** argument of the **Close** method.
>
> The following macro closes the workbook without saving changes:
>
> ```vb
> Sub CloseBook2()
>     ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Thank you! I used the CloseBook() method.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you have above is for `VBA` - you can address this in your `VBS` directly by using

```
oWorkBook.Close False
Set oWorkBook = Nothing
```

in place of

```
Set oWorkBook = Nothing
```